# Text is larger than it should be. I need to remove the white space

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

The text on my website has spaces at the top but not at the bottom. You can therefore see in this image that the visual result is not the best as you can see that the central text is not centered:
[image]

[image]

I've tried using margin 0 and padding 0 but nothing seems to work. I also had no results with the other methods I found online. I attach the css code of my site text:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
    color: var(--txtColor);
    font-family: "myFont";
    font-size: calc(15px + 0.390625vw);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--txtColor);
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it. Thanks all in advance.

I'm also attaching a simple snippet showing the problem. Look carefully at the space between the central text and those that surround it. It will be different:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
    color: var(--txtColor);
    font-family: "myFont";
    font-size: calc(15px + 0.390625vw);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--txtColor);
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Text bla bla bla</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text bla bla bla</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need the HTML as well. In the SO editor, you can use the icon with the page that has `<>` on it to add your exact case that causes this so that we can view all pieces of it together and see that it is reproducible. Please use the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did as you asked

Comment: There is basically nothing you can do here. That space is built into the font glyph deliberately and css cannot remove it.

Comment: my gosh! is there any other way to make the center text sag then?

Answer (score 1):

The element's font-size is properly calculated, even though I can't be sure because the `0.390625vw` depends on the viewport.

The "space" around the element is a result of the `line-height`, which is — depending on the font-family — often around `1.2` times the font size (e.g. `1,2em`). Because of the large font-size of the `h1`-element, the effect of the 1.2 multiplier is quite visible.

Setting `line-height: 1` for the `h1` element would change the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the try but I've already tried this. The font I'm using is exo 2. Your solution decreases the height of my text area but it won't be centered, the tail will hang out of its area and therefore still be lower than it should be

Comment: The `line-height` multiplier depends on the font you use. In case of your embedded example it seems to be around 1.3. So, using `line-height: calc(1/1.3)` results in the text-box matching the height of the text. Strictly this only counts for the capital letter `M`, this is where the unit `em` comes from. So only uppercased letters will fill the vertical space, lower-cased letters will leave space inside the text-box. If you want such special text-positioning control HTML/CSS is not the way, SVG might better suit your case.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clear answer to my problem